# Ckeditor moves <?xml ...> tag

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

I use the ckeditor wysiwyg editor (version 4.4.7 Standard) with `fullPage=true`.

This is the input html string:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="de">
<head>
    ...
</head>
<body>
    ...
</body>
</html>
```

I set this with string with `instance.setData(str)`, but when I do `instance.getData()` I get the following html, with the `<?xml ...>` tag moved to the second position after the doctype tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html>
<head>
    ...
</head>
<body>
    ...
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a **[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/LLye4LLf/3/)** to demonstrate the problem.

Why is that?
Can I move the tag to the top of the output string?

In general: How can I change the output of "static" tags like `doctype` or `?xml`?

Comment: Have you read their documentation?

Comment: Yes of course. But I got stuck. I've tried with `dataFilter.addRules` and `htmlFilter.addRules`, but the doctype and the xml tag are not in the set of elements you can edit